# Where to get NCover from?

Tags: .net, ncover

I realise NCover has gone commercial. I am looking for the free version. Where do i get the latest free version of NCover?

The NCover website only talks about a trial version of the commercial product, not the free version.

Answer (score 16):

the commercial NCover vendors still make the free version available here

http://downloads.ncover.com/NCover-1.5.8.zip

Comment: The link is leading to a Walled-Garden that force to create an account but bugmenot save the day as most of the time http://www.bugmenot.com/view/ncover.com

Comment: Additionally the direct download don't require to be logged-in : http://downloads.ncover.com/NCover-1.5.8.zip

Comment: The link in the answer is not valid any more (as of this moment). But the one from the comment above is still valid. Here is also another link: http://code.google.com/p/jabr/downloads/detail?name=NCover-1.5.8.zip

Answer (score 4):

Download Test Driven.net http://testdriven.net/download.aspx (a great tool)

It uses the free version of ncover, after installation you can look here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\TestDriven.NET 3\NCover\1.5.8

Answer (score 3):

NCover is a commercial product now. You can check [PartCover](https://sourceforge.net/projects/partcover/) as an alternative.

Comment: PartCover does not seem to work with class library codebase. It seems to work only with EXE files. Is this correct, or do they support class libraries as well - i.e. dll code.

Comment: You do it by running your tests using the console runner of your test framework (NUnit.Console.exe, etc).

Comment: PartCover does support class library checking as well.

Comment: PartCover isn't being developed anymore. OpenCover the de facto alternative. https://github.com/sawilde/opencover