# Nant build failing with NCover

Tags: .net, nant, ncover

I am currently setting up NCover as part of our CC.NET continuous integration. I've downloaded NCover 1.0.1 from sourceforge, and put the relevent DLLs into the correct nant folder so I can use the tasks in my build file.

The build process instruments our source code correctly, and then goes on to build the solution using MSBuild.

At this point, the build fails giving me the error:

"NCover does not exist in the current context".

I can resolve that by including NCover.dll in the relevent projects in the solution, but this is not ideal - we don't want to be including this DLL in our releases etc.

What is best practice to get the build to see NCover.dll? Should it be included in our projects or should we be copying the dll to the correct place before building? Or something else entirely...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the [right version of NCover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333711/where-to-get-ncover-from) (probably you want the free but discontinued version from Gnoso) first and see if this already fixes the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure this will help as it's the project build that fails due to NCover.dll being missing... I'll give it a shot though