# how to use NCover in console/command line?

Tags: ncover

i've downloaded a free version of ncover here -> http://sourceforge.net/projects/ncover/

but unortunately i am unable to find steps on how to use it in the command line.

any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333711/where-to-get-ncover-from).

There are two free versions of NCover available: The SourceForge one (which is discontinued and not working well as Try's comment on [Ira Baxter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333711/where-to-get-ncover-from/1333737#1333737) shows) and the Gnoso one (which used to be free and has gone commercial after version 1.5.8). Get the latter one from [here](http://downloads.ncover.com/NCover-1.5.8.zip).

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps somebody else. I was able to get NCover 1.5.8 (one that comes with TestDriven.NET) working nicely with nunit.

```
NCover.Console.exe nunit-console-x86.exe /noshadow yourAssembly.dll
```

The only trick was to makes sure CoverLib.dll COM component is properly registered

```
regsrv32 CoverLib.dll
```

Otherwise you'd get "Profiled Process Terminated" error, and then making sure we are passing /noshadow parameter to nunit, otherwise NCover would fail to load symbols for the assembly (at least in my case).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180434/how-to-calculate-code-coverage-with-ncover-using-jenkins).

Steps to solve

1.Need to monitor the execution of Test cases Using ncover-console.exe

"[path]\NCover.Console.exe" "[path]\nunit- console.exe" "E:\Myapp\test.sln" /xml="[PATH]\TestResult.xml"

This will create a .nccov file

2.Create coverage html report from .nccov file using NCover.Reporting.exe

"[path]\NCover\NCover.Reporting.exe" "[path]\coverage.nccov" //or FullCoverageReport:Html:output

Comment: hi is it necessary to have nunit console for this as I have used mbunit so is there any way to use ncover console with for mbunit tests

Comment: @priya :hi , as i don't have much exposure in mbunit, since i am working with an organization once i am free i will have a look on it and let u know about mbunit